# Fancybox YouTube Video not working on Localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, fancybox

I am having an issue getting Fancybox's YouTube video implementation working on my localhost.  When I load the page I get this error:

`Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://sites:8888/clients/project_name/v1/products/index from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/RtXSVGsQ8N0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

I obviously want to make sure the implementation is working correctly before I push it to the live server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are either trying to do a cross domain ajax call. Whats your browser?

Comment: Safari on Mac, is there any cross-domain file I can add to the page headers to allow this on localhost?

Comment: Nopes. It is for security reasons and quite rightly so. So, your best bet would be to use an iframe youtube code.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify on **ToyDaVirus**, make sure you specify **type** as **iframe** in parameters.

i.e. `'type' : 'iframe'`

---

```
$('#selector').click(function() {

        $.fancybox({

        'padding'           : 10,
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'centerOnScroll'    : true,
        'overlayColor'      : '#000',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'title'             : this.title,
        'width'             : 680,
        'height'            : 495,
        'href'              : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'              : 'iframe',

        'swf'               : {
            'wmode'             : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }

        });

        return false;
});
```